# Bootable USBs no longer appear at startup

Tags: usb, startup, windows, dual-boot

I recently had my Macbook (early 2015) reset after a bootloader mess up I won't get into. When I got it back I found that it would no longer show bootable USBs at startup in the boot menu even though it definitely recognised them as seen in Finder. The BUSBs definitely work as they have been tested on other computers, namely Windows 7, Windows 10 and a Debian box I have. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do other USB work ?

Comment: When you say "reset" do you mean you erased the disk and reinstalled or did you just install a new copy of Mac OS X? And I think the "boot loader mess up" might need some detail, because I've never heard of that and can't figure out what you mean. Oh, have you tried setting the PRAM (Command-Option-P-R at boot up)?